# Calling A Method With null param

Tags: kotlin

In java we can call a method `aMethod(val1 , val2)`

with `classObject.aMethod(null_if_Val1_NotAvailable,val2)`
And inside the Method i will check that if val1 is null
i will initialize that

How to do the same in Kotlin.
I tried but its saying Null Cannot be value of Non-null type

Comment: In Kotlin language reference, this is clearly covered:  http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use default values:

```
fun aMethod(val1: String = "default value", val2: String)
```

You can now use the default method like so:

```
classObject.aMethod(val2 = "val2")
```

Comment: Or swap `val1` and `val2` so there is no need to use named parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way

```
fun printHello(name: String?): Unit {
    if (name != null)
        println("Hello ${name}")
    else
        println("Hi there!")
    // `return Unit` or `return` is optional
}
```

Return type as your wish.
Refrence from [kotlin langauge function tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html)

`?` after the datatype allows you to have null. refer [this link](http://codeofrob.com/entries/looking-at-kotlin---the-rest-of-it.html)

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin emphasis on null safety. If you want a property/return type/parameter/local variable to be null, you will have to use [*nullable types*](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html), by appending a question mark to the end of your type.

e.g.

```
Foo foo = null // doesn't compile
Foo? foo = null // compiles

fun foo(foo: Foo)
foo(null) // doesn't compile

fun bar(foo: Foo?)
bar(null) // compiles

fun foo(): Foo = null // doesn't compile
fun foo(): Foo? = null // compiles
```

So in order to make your code works, all you need is to specify that function `aMethod` takes a nullable type:

```
fun aMethod(val1: SomeType?, val2) {
    //...
}
```

However, in kotlin, it's not suggested to use null here. We have a better way to deal with your situation. We use *default parameters*, as suggested by nhaarman.

```
fun aMethod(val1: SomeType = someDefaultValue, val2: OtherType) {
    //...
}
aMethod(val2 = OtherType())
```